# Class, Category, Type

Tags: meaning, usage

Could it be that this sentence using "*type*":

> 1a. A cat belongs to a ***type*** of animal.

is less common than similar sentences using "*class*" or "*category*" like the following?

> 1b. A cat belongs to a ***class*** of animal.
>   1c. A cat belongs to a ***category*** of animal.

Comment: [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=belongs+to+a+type%2C+belongs+to+a+class%2C+belongs+to+a+category&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbelongs%20to%20a%20type%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbelongs%20to%20a%20class%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbelongs%20to%20a%20category%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just wrote a [long answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/70469/6700) about why **type** and **member** don't go together. That answer explains that the word **type** suggests a model or ideal of which instances are imperfect or slightly varying copies rather than a whole or collection that contains parts or members.

### belong

The primary sense of **belong** means standing in an appropriate relationship to something greater or more fundamental, as property belongs to a person, a person belongs to a family, a member belongs to a club, dishes belong in the kitchen, a talented violinist belongs in a good orchestra, etc. The meaning is very similar to the possessive or genitive case, which can sometimes express the same relationship: John's fishing rods, the club's newest member, etc.

**Belong** doesn't clash with **type** as strongly as **member** does, but it clashes, so indeed your example 1a is less common. Usually in English you use the possessive or genitive in the other direction with **type**: "the cat**'s** type is Maine Coon"; "the cat is a type **of** animal".

### class

Just as the etymology of **type** explained why it leads people today to think of an abstraction as a separate individual from its instances, the etymologies of **class** and **category** explain why these words lead people to think of an abstraction as a group or collection.

**Class** [in Latin](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=classis) meant a division of the Roman people into higher and lower ranks, or various divisions of armies or people in military service. Over the centuries in English, the word has been extended into [many senses](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/class#English), but they all preserve the idea of dividing a large collection into smaller collections arranged by similarity, as when **classifying**, or distinguishing the highest-ranking individuals as when we say that someone has "class" or a book is "a classic".

This makes **class** a natural fit with **belong** and **member**. It seems axiomatic to say that people belong with others of their same class. Since a class is a (sub-)collection, each individual is a part. Unlike the metaphor of **type**, it doesn't make sense to think of a class without members. A class *is* its members. Its members are the ones who belong together because of their similarity.

### category

The word **category** has a somewhat [complex history](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/48118/6700), originating from an Ancient Greek word that today we would translate into English as "predicate": something that you can say *about* something. For example, in "Maine Coons are large cats", "large cats" is the predicate, said about Maine Coons. Over time, in English, **category** has come to mean the collection of all the things that the same predicate is true of. For example, the category of "four wheeled-cars" is all cars that have four wheels. Choose any car from that category, and "that car has four wheels" will be true, because that is how the category is defined.

Again, since the word **category** makes you think of a collection of things that have something in common, it has a natural fit with **belong** and **member**.

### How to say it

> The cat **is** a type of animal. [Here, "the" is a determiner meaning that we are using "cat" as the name of a type.]
>
> *Cat* **is** a type of animal. [Omitting the determiner also means that we are using "cat" as the name of a type.]
>
> The cat **belongs to** the class of all animals. [In other words, "all animals" is a class, of which "the cat" is a subclass.]
>
> *Cat* **belongs to** the category *animal.* [In other words, *animal* is a category, of which *cat* is a subcategory.]
>
> Purrcolator **belongs to** the class *cat.* [In other words, Purrcolator is a cat.]

Answer (score 4):

I would say that "type" is the more common of the options. "Kind" may also be used. Note that typically it's

> A cat *is* a type of animal

**EDIT (expansion)**

A type is not something you *belong to*, it's something you are. A talent agent might say "He's a Tom Cruise type".

Classes and categories (and pigeon holes) are something you're *in*.

Comment: So, "*a cat* ***is*** *a type of animal*" is more common than "*a cat* ***belongs*** *to a type of animal*"?

Comment: @meatie as a native speaker yes, the answer given here is what is common and natural sounding. Saying a cat belongs to a type of animal isn't even accurate anyway. You could say a cat belongs to a certain group of animals (the group being whatever, domestic, etc). But it doesn't belong to a type of animal, it is a type of animal in its own right.

Comment: So, [this](http://www.nytimes.com/2006/06/16/us/16suburbs.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0):  "*As the population changes, he said, those voters no longer* ***fit neatly into partisan types***", would be wrong?

Comment: @meatie That sentence is correct, but you should ask about it in a new question. Explaining it requires a whole different answer. (I'll do my best to fight off people who say it's a duplicate.)